# Why isn't typescript giving me typing error here?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code, with two extended classes:

```
interface payloadCollection {
    [key: string]: payloadObject<object, object>
}

 type payloadObject<TExpectedData extends object = {}, TExpectedResponse extends object = {}> = {
    request: TExpectedData,
    response: TExpectedResponse
}

class Communicator<
    TListeners extends payloadCollection, 
    TBroadcasters extends payloadCollection
> {

    broadcasters!: TBroadcasters;

    send<
        TMessage extends keyof TBroadcasters, 
        TData extends TBroadcasters[TMessage]['request'], 
        TResponse extends TBroadcasters[TMessage]['response']>(message: TMessage, data: TData): TResponse {
            return '' as any;
    }

    addListener<
        TMessage extends keyof TListeners,
        TData extends TListeners[TMessage]['request'],
        TResponse extends TListeners[TMessage]['response']
    >(message: TMessage, callback: (data: TData) => TResponse) {}
}

type extendedCommunicatorListeners = {
    'extendedListener': payloadObject<{
        type: string
    }, {
        responseType: string
    }>;
}

interface extendedCommunicatorBroadcasters extends payloadCollection {
    'extendedBroadcaster': payloadObject<{
        type: string
    }, {
        responseType: string
    }>
}

class ExtendedCommunicator<
    TListeners extends extendedCommunicatorListeners = extendedCommunicatorListeners,
    TBroadcasters extends extendedCommunicatorBroadcasters = extendedCommunicatorBroadcasters
> 
    extends Communicator<TListeners, TBroadcasters> {


        private innerMethod() {
            /** No typing help here, if I try to ask intellisense for first parameter suggestions, I receive none. However, 
             *  if I introduce the first parameter, the second parameter receives suggestions, and the response type is also correct.  */
            const response = this.send("extendedBroadcaster", {
                type: 'test'
            });
        }   
    }

const testExtendedCommunicator: ExtendedCommunicator = new ExtendedCommunicator();

/** No typing help here either, and no error on invalid method */
testExtendedCommunicator.send("invalidMethod", {
    invalidData: 15
});
```

I am trying to create a generic class function, which receives parameters based on the extending parents generic parameter. However, typescript not only does not give me suggestions on the possible send methods, but it neither does show me error, when I try to use a parameter on the first method, which should not be usable.

Here's a [playground link also](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgA5wJ4BsD2cAmAwjllhAmMDiMgN4BQyTyA2gNYQYBcyAzmFFABzALo902PPgDyAIwBW5MAB4cCpQBpkaxRQB89AL71GYDKhQTcBObpUAVAKIAPCxQj4AInDBxkEZ0gQfF5tdQpkAF46Qy0nVyUPACUIXlRqXhQAoJCwuyiYvQKGZmQoCABHAFdUsB54t0gvHzgNRmZytIyIepdG5NT0kEyjEwQsOF5Q4gBbGaqQYAQfHChldqZ7ABlgfggQaFDs-dyrKWJSJSoQLQ3kewAhKCllvagjwJPQs4ILsgprvQigw7rJngRXpB3gBCepPF6TKG8ADcJlKmWC61KpXsAFlUrw4EIsp9gqEOBgcDB7vCIYjDrdscx7N5fP5SblHuD8JDDiw8QSiRARCwAOTlaq1UUiRlM+4pLrDEk5UJchFvXj8-FTIUi8WDbrSvQAChmguJ9W1hOJWnwLXqrLgAEp6gqhpk6Hc5WUIGAqlAaKLRchJiGQBhUaVjHcCPgdnsDmsvcyrUL2SrkBSqfd40EGcnNo7018c7s8+8tebhWKJTV+NK2t77G7usWyaWE3yBTriXrOu6INK7iazT2evdUzbkMtSLJEGweMa7b4HS0nVEis2DUr17RjNGzBY2-gPLN5otlmBVrn9odindRcdgh4b4nReJMNYZOEVCU5Yfx34QQQCEO5Yk9b1+26exzEAgRhDAvRUWjUAoXgJBj1PHA5gWJYVigWkeXpd5j2+T9zhIf5KGoCDmEfDkPEI3koHfNByJsH9lD-JkAJ4ICEKjLRuOxKClRgiw+PgkDENGehxkmUIXByLCcIvfCsWZV87yfXIdJU888KvKAtJI6I9KIbCDMva8y1vd5G2ZJjiI+DNzLPXDrII7lmNCMyGIs1TDNWJyNSBZA7h06ZLI89TtlsxNeDiEKkWBEwCzQQQADcfBQUBE3xMAAAscHwY1d3S0oAHoACpquQAA5HBkEPYRkEKiAsFQNroAgLRgGpABJZqoAwZqmsmNhkFQjqsF2fYPRgVZkBgYB3jANioDgM0oT4KohGJfhrkS5AhvKJBgEylAQGoCAADpkAACRwAB3CBLqgWVvWYOqpsGqbwGefAqgwoqUBWtaNq231oC0UG+HIah8Eh7boB9c7LtCXg9oO6jhi0OBgma9qfUVD0AKm0I4CwXgmoQVYzrAe7kGqyqKuYOnhnW0SPWiIrdlujFSoAInM5LoCFoS2Z42CeFFSB6yl5BDCdSM5UMZgwLGDJ1vlsAlJOfSYqMnh9efAKrPwgoDme5BTZPc2jdWMrUXoGq6sa5rzFa9rOu68p-GAUGPrDJHrv8KBnigbQaFAbLZqR7biqRln6F1u3DbUoyBZOY0hdjqngHwAqk4l2imHz+PHR4ABGABWIwVaAA)

Answer (score 1):

If you change

```
interface extendedCommunicatorBroadcasters extends payloadCollection {
    'extendedBroadcaster': payloadObject<{
        type: string
    }, {
        responseType: string
    }>
}
```

to

```
type extendedCommunicatorBroadcasters = {
    'extendedBroadcaster': payloadObject<{
        type: string
    }, {
        responseType: string
    }>
}
```

then you should at least get errors on wrong keys everywhere. I then get IntelliSense aswell on the last line, but not on usages in the class itself. I assume this is because the optional generics can be overwritten and that therefore doesn't allow TypeScript to narrow/specify the keys until an actual instance is created (where you either specified other generics, or left the optionals intact).

If you wanted IntelliSense immediately in the class as well - because you would want the type to be the predefined one - you could change the ExtendedCommunicator to pass the second generic to Communicator as `extendedCommunicatorBroadcasters` like so:

```
class ExtendedCommunicator<
        TListeners extends extendedCommunicatorListeners = extendedCommunicatorListeners,
    > extends Communicator<TListeners, extendedCommunicatorBroadcasters> {
        private innerMethod() {
            /** should have intellisense and errors on wrong key */
            const response = this.send("extendedBroadcaster", { type: "test" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: but this way, I have no way of extending the broadcasters part unfortunately. I will try the first part of your propositon and report back though.

Comment: well with the payloadCollection you are technically saying you allow every key to be acceptable (key: string), and typescript can't infer before instantiation (and even after if you leave the optional generic, since in your example, it extends payloadCollection, which accepts any key) to which keys it will be narrowed - if you want to specify a mapped type with certain keys you can type it as:
type .... = { [key in <YourKeyType>]: payloadObject<...> }

Comment: Basically, I am using the `payloadCollection` for the sole purpose so that typescript is not complaining that `TMessage extends keyof TListeners, TData extends TListeners[TMessage]['request']` "request" is not a valid key of `TListeners[TMessage]` here.